# list all connected devices on windows

Tags: c#, windows, controlpanel, input-devices

How can I get all connected devices using c# like in Control Panel\Hardware and Sound\Devices and Printers ?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to add a reference to System.Management in your project, then you can experiment something like this:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1 {
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Management; // need to add System.Management to your project references.

    class Program {
        static void Main(string[] args) {
            var usbDevices = GetUSBDevices();

            foreach(var usbDevice in usbDevices) {
                Console.WriteLine("Device ID: {0}, PNP Device ID: {1}, Description: {2}", usbDevice.DeviceID, usbDevice.PnpDeviceID, usbDevice.Description);
            }

            Console.Read();
        }

        static List < USBDeviceInfo > GetUSBDevices() {
            List < USBDeviceInfo > devices = new List < USBDeviceInfo > ();

            ManagementObjectCollection collection;
            using(var searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(@"Select * From Win32_USBHub"))
            collection = searcher.Get();

            foreach(var device in collection) {
                devices.Add(new USBDeviceInfo((string) device.GetPropertyValue("DeviceID"), (string) device.GetPropertyValue("PNPDeviceID"), (string) device.GetPropertyValue("Description")));
            }

            collection.Dispose();
            return devices;
        }
    }

    class USBDeviceInfo {
        public USBDeviceInfo(string deviceID, string pnpDeviceID, string description) {
            this.DeviceID = deviceID;
            this.PnpDeviceID = pnpDeviceID;
            this.Description = description;
        }
        public string DeviceID {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string PnpDeviceID {
            get;
            private set;
        }
        public string Description {
            get;
            private set;
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Friendly names

```
ManagementObjectCollection mbsList = null;
            ManagementObjectSearcher mbs = new ManagementObjectSearcher("Select * From Win32_USBHub");
            mbsList = mbs.Get();

            foreach (ManagementObject mo in mbsList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("USBHub device Friendly name:{0}", mo["Name"].ToString());
            }
```

Comment: Thanks.
this partialy works, how can I get the model name like specified in the control panel?

Comment: The model? like in the model of the device?

Comment: I tried this, unfortunately the output is different from how it's presented in the control panel, any idea how to get the display name?